# Unable to start a Validator Node in Hyperledger Sawtooth. Docker unable to validate certificate

Tags: docker, docker-compose, blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am trying the command `docker-compose up` to start the Validator Node in my Hyperledger Sawtooth setup on my Ubuntu machine.

I am running this command behind my company's proxy.

When I use the command `docker-compose up`, I get the following output:

```
    Building validator
Step 1/15 : FROM ubuntu:xenial
 ---> 4a689991aa24
Step 2/15 : RUN echo "deb http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/ci xenial universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list  && (apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 8AA7AF1F1091A5FD  || apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 8AA7AF1F1091A5FD)  && apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 59b3dd0413ec
Step 3/15 : RUN apt-get install -y -q --allow-downgrades     git     python3     python3-stdeb
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fa792ef3800a
Step 4/15 : RUN apt-get install -y -q --allow-downgrades     python3-grpcio     python3-grpcio-tools     python3-protobuf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b21e9522d61d
Step 5/15 : RUN apt-get install -y -q --allow-downgrades     python3-cbor     python3-colorlog     python3-cryptography>=1.7.1     python3-dev     python3-lmdb     python3-netifaces=0.10.4-0.1build2     python3-pyformance     python3-secp256k1     python3-toml     python3-yaml     python3-zmq     unzip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bff0f3b39a0a
Step 6/15 : RUN curl -OLsS https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.5.1/protoc-3.5.1-linux-x86_64.zip  && unzip protoc-3.5.1-linux-x86_64.zip -d protoc3  && rm protoc-3.5.1-linux-x86_64.zip
 ---> Running in 37e4dd702373
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
ERROR: Service 'validator' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c curl -OLsS https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.5.1/protoc-3.5.1-linux-x86_64.zip  && unzip protoc-3.5.1-linux-x86_64.zip -d protoc3  && rm protoc-3.5.1-linux-x86_64.zip' returned a non-zero code: 60
```

It says that the server verification failed and stops at step(6/15).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the key for the repository.
For the stable repository, use:
`$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 8AA7AF1F1091A5FD
$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/bumper/stable xenial universe'`

For the nightly, development repository use:
`$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 44FC67F19B2466EA
$ sudo apt-add-repository 'deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/nightly xenial universe'`